# Density DPI of Samsung Galaxy S10 too small?

Tags: android

I've been getting device density like this:

```
val wm = getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager
val display = wm.defaultDisplay
val metrics = DisplayMetrics()
display.getMetrics(metrics)
val density = metrics.densityDpi
```

Then I based some logic on the value of `density` and constants:

- `DENSITY_XHIGH`
- `DENSITY_XXHIGH`

I expected S10 to fall under `DENSITY_XXHIGH` but apparently it's `density` value is **420**, contrary to S9 which density is **480**.

1. Does that mean that S10 is actually using resources from xhdpi and not xxhdpi folder?
2. If this value is not reliable what value should I base on my logic for choosing optimal image size before I load int into `ImageView`?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to know what is used, I suggest to create a "whoami" string and place it in `values-xhdpi` and all other *dpi variants.

*values-xhdpi/whoami.xml*

```
<resources>
    <string name="density_bucket" translatable="false">xhdpi</string>
</resources>
```

If you use that value, you know what the Android system selects from during runtime.

As this is a nice way for "debugging" your question to a specific device, you can also adopt to this. In my case this value is used to request the right image sizes from an asset backend.